# add classes to wp_list_categories

Tags: wordpress, wp-list-categories

I am displaying all the categories of custom taxonomy like this:

```
<?php
    $taxonomy     = 'question';
    $orderby      = 'name';
    $show_count   = false;
    $pad_counts   = false;
    $hierarchical = true;
    $title        = '';

    $args = array(
        'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
        'orderby'      => $orderby,
        'show_count'   => $show_count,
        'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
        'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
        'title_li'     => $title
    );
    ?>

    <section class="cd-faq">
        <ul class="cd-faq-categories">
            <?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
        </ul> <!-- cd-faq-categories -->

    </section>
```

What i want to do is give different classes to each list item. Like this:

```
<ul class="cd-faq-categories">
        <li><a class="selected" href="#basics">Basics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#mobile">Mobile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#account">Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="#payments">Payments</a></li>
        <li><a href="#privacy">Privacy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#delivery">Delivery</a></li>
    </ul> <!-- cd-faq-categories -->
```

how can i do this?

Comment: Instead of using wp_list_categories, use get_categories and loop through each individually to style it the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have two possible solutions - parse the output code through the **wp_list_categories** filter, which have a full access to the final code outputed by the **wp_list_categories** function. But in this case you will affect also other calls of the **wp_list_categories** function.

Other solution is to create own function based on the **wp_list_categories** code but i.e. modified to add CSS clases based on the category slug.

You can find a full source code of the **wp_list_categories** function [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/).

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="our__list">
  <?php 
    $categories = get_categories( [
      'taxonomy'     => 'category',
      'type'         => 'post',
      'child_of'     => 0,
      'parent'       => '',
      'orderby'      => 'name',
      'order'        => 'ASC',
      'hide_empty'   => 1,
      'hierarchical' => 1,
      'exclude'      => '',
      'include'      => '',
      'number'       => 0,
      'pad_counts'   => false,
    ] );

    if( $categories ) {
      foreach( $categories as $cat ) {

    ?>
      <li class="our__list-class">
        <a 
          href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"
         >
          <?php echo $cat->name; ?>
        </a>
      </li>
  <?php
      }
    }
  ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- POST ARCHIVE CATEGORIES : begin -->
<ul class="post-archive-categories">
<?php
$my_walker= new Walker_Category_Custom();
wp_list_categories(array('walker'=>$my_walker,'orderby'=>'name','title_li' => '','hide_empty'=>0));
?>
</ul>
<!-- POST ARCHIVE CATEGORIES : end -->
```

Walker class

```
class Walker_Category_Custom extends Walker_Category {

function start_lvl(&$output, $depth=0, $args=array()) {
$output .= "\n<ul class='post-archive-categories__list'>\n";
}

function end_lvl(&$output, $depth=0, $args=array()) {
$output .= "</ul>\n";
}

function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array(),$current_object_id = 0) {
$output.= '<li id="nav-menu-item-'. $item->ID . '" class="post-archive-categories__item post-archive-categories__item--category"><a href="'.home_url('category/'.$item->slug).'/" class="post-archive-categories__item-link">

'.esc_attr($item->name);
//<img src="http://working.local/images/'.($item->slug).'.jpg">
}

function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array()) {
$output .= "</a></li>\n";
}
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I'm glad I could help but I'm sorry to hear that, don't forget we don't all have enough time to do it, I'll try to explain later in the evening.